# IOC dependency injection deployment (bin ? GAC ?)

Tags: dependency-injection, hosting, shared-hosting

Are there any deployment requirements for the most popular IOC containers (example: Windsor, Ninject, Unity, StructureMap, Autofac) ?  Do they all deploy the same?

If you're on a shared host, what challenges will that present (ex. medium trust, etc...)

Can they be bin deployed?  GAC deployed?

Any web-hosters that come "IOC-ready"?

Answer (score 2):

Most of the IOC frameworks works with private assemblies and i dont know much Web hosters that allows you to deploy files into the GAC.